# It is possible to see Wordpress login access log?

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, logging

I made Wordpress my linux server on CentOS7, Apache/2.4.6, PHP 5.6.31 .  when I used wordpress, I thought about Wordpress login access log. I want to see who log on my wordpress. I saw /var/log/httpd/access_log , there was no login information.

For example, When I log on wordpress by ID :xxx Password:1234, It is possible when I see the log, the log show me like [16/Oct/2017:23:15:33 +0900] ID:xxx Password:1234 log on the wordpress.

when I use wordpress plugin, It show access log, but my wish is just see the log, than I know who log on the wordpress, and password.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not have an activity logger however there are plugins that will achieve this for you. For example [this one here](https://www.cre8d-design.com/2007/07/wordpress-plugin-login-logger/)